# Install rpm package: missing requires of (installed) program error

Tags: gnuplot, rpm, yum

I am trying to install a package I built that requires gnuplot.

I currently have gnuplot installed on my CentOS machine:

```
$ which gnuplot
/usr/bin/gnuplot

$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 2
```

But when I am trying to install the package, I have the following error:

```
$ sudo yum install my_package.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining my_package.rpm: my_package.x86_64
Marking my_package.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package my_package will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/gnuplot for package: my_package.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                             |  30 kB  00:00:00     
 [...]
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/gnuplot for package: my_package.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/gnuplot for package: my_package.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: my_package.x86_64 (/my_package)
       Requires: /usr/bin/gnuplot
Error: Package: my_package.x86_64 (installed)
       Requires: /usr/bin/gnuplot
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
my_package.x86_64 has missing requires of /usr/bin/gnuplot
```

If I use rpm, I have the same issue:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh my_package.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/gnuplot is needed by my_package.x86_64
```

Since gnuplot is installed, I do not understand why yum is complaining...

Comment: Try `rpm -q gnuplot` and `rpm -q /usr/bin/gnuplot`. The required package name is `gnuplot`. Your custom rpm is listing the requirement as `/usr/bin/gnuplot`. You should fix your package with the correct require name/version.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. My spec file says "Requires: gnuplot >= 4.2" and I have a "gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6" installed... so it should be ok ?

Comment: In this case, are you sure your current gnuplot was installed with rpm ? See the commands I added in front of my comment above. The requirement will not be satisfied if it was installed manually. It needs to be an rpm package installed via yum or rpm

Comment: Indeed : `$ rpm -q gnuplot -> gnuplot-4.2.6-2.el6.x86_64` and `$ rpm -q /usr/bin/gnuplot -> package /usr/bin/gnuplot is not installed` but... in my spec file I said "gnuplot" and not "/usr/bin/gnuplot"... so what should I write in my spec file ?

Comment: At this point we are far beyond my rpm packaging skills... anyone else ?

Comment: Ok, I understood the root cause. My package is packaging a script beginning with `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot --persist` and /usr/bin/gnuplot was not installed with rpm... so this is why rpm is complaining... but I have no clue on how to fix this.

Comment: Can you uninstall gnuplot and reinstall with rpm? I've never had great luck in the past getting stuff I've built to respect dependencies from a package management system, and vice versa.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot... :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed it by modifying the shebang of my script and :

```
#!/bin/bash
[...]
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
[...]
EOFMarker
```

This is clearly a hack but it is working because when installing the rpm it is no more complaining about /usr/bin/gnuplot that is not installed.

Comment: This is basically "cheating" by fooling the RPM's scanning scripts; the proper way to disable this is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You figured out in the comments the problem - RPM doesn't care what's on your system; it only cares about what is in its database. If you didn't install `gnuplot` via RPM, it doesn't know it's there.

The only "proper" answer to this is installing tools on your machine using RPM (which is that `yum` or `dnf` behind-the-scenes). These tools have been around for a long long time for good reason - you can easily ensure your software will run on the target box without assumptions.

That said, if you *want* to make a malformed RPM that simply *assumes* that `gnuplot` is there, you can add to your RPM specfile `AutoReqProv: no` (see [this reference](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html)). If you do that, you'll probably want to add many manual `Requires` lines covering everything else. You should also tweak your scripts that use `gnuplot` to no longer assume it is there and explicitly check for it first returning a useful message to the user if it isn't, like "you need to install gnuplot."